# Searching by date range

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a search criteria that is tied into a mySQL DB, by date range, but it does not seem to return expected results so far.

The dates are stored in the following format: `mm/dd/yy` and I would simply like to sort by date range, so if the user would enters the dates `From: 2/2/12` to `<current date>` than the query will return all queries the fall in that date range including the current date.

This is what I tried:

I have testing `workorder` records in the DB with the following timestamps: 1362250990 and 1362251039.

PHP

```
$date1 = strtotime($_GET['dateFirst']);
$date2 = strtotime($_GET['dateSecond']);
echo $date1 . '> work order date <='. $date2;
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM workorders WHERE (work_order_date > $date1) AND (work_order_date <= $date2) LIMIT 20");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates should ALWAYS be stored in a suitable column type (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, or preferably `TIMESTAMP`).

This automatically makes them easily sortable, since they are in big-endian order.

Assuming your input formats are reliable, you can then use the `BETWEEN` comparison operator like this:

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_GET['dateFirst']);
$date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_GET['dateSecond']);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `workorders` WHERE `work_order_date` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the following error: `A non well formed numeric value encountered` with this implementation.

Comment: Rest assured, I am not that creative when it comes to making up wierd sounding errors ;)

Comment: Do my dates HAVE to be stored as `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` for this implementation to work?

Comment: It is highly recommended, yes. They should really be in that format already. What is the `$_GET` variable's value?

Comment: Are you sure of that? Have you confirmed with a `var_dump` that the values are there? Where exactly is the error occuring?

Comment: Yes I am sure of that. 100,000% sure! The exact error is `A non well formed numeric value encountered` on the following lines `$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_GET['dateFirst']);` and `$date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_GET['dateSecond']);`

Comment: Hmm... try wrapping `intval()` around the `$_GET` variables.